# Is there an intuitive way to understand a sequential Monte Carlo Markov Chain?

Tags: monte-carlo

I was wondering if there was an intuitive way to understand what a sequential Monte Carlo Markov Chain is. It also goes by the name of particle filtering. Is there an intuitive way to think about it/teach it to someone? Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more precise? For instance point out the entries you have read so far and explain why it is not sufficiently intuitive. I acknowledge the Wikipedia page is too advanced for most readers, but Nando de Freitas has [Matlab codes](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~nando/smc/) on line that could help you. And the [on-line course of Arnaud Doucet for the MLSS 2012](http://yosinski.com/mlss12/MLSS-2012-Doucet-Sequential-Monte-Carlo-Methods/) is quite accessible.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean 'sequential Monte Carlo' rather than 'sequential Monte Carlo Markov Chain'? Otherwise, do you have a reference for the term 'sequential Monte Carlo Markov Chain'?

Answer (score -1):

The term is "Markov Chain Monte Carlo" and it is a technique used for approximating expectations/integrals involving probability distributions that are difficult to sample from.

Monte Carlo methods require sampling to approximate expectations.  The Markov Chain is the tool used to sample.  In particular this method is used when one has access to a *non normalized probability mass/density function*.

A Markov Chain is a probabilistic model for movement on a graph.  I will let you look up the details.  Consider a random walk on a Markov Chain with states $X_0, X_1, \dots$.  Suppose we start the walk at state $s$.  Now consider:

$$
P(X_n = t | X_0 = s).
$$

When $n$ is small this depends greatly on the starting state, but as $n$ goes to infinity (under reasonable Markov Chain assumptions that I'll let you look up) this converges to a distribution that does not depend on $s$.

In MCMC we construct a Markov Chain whose stationary distribution *is* the distribution we're trying to sample from.  Then a sufficiently long random walk on that Markov Chain closely resembles drawing samples from that distribution.  The construction of this Markov Chain is too involved for this post, but you can look up Metropolis Hastings.  I hope this helped with the intuition.

**edit**

My apologies.  The word sequential didn't give me the sense that this was a separate idea (there are many sequences in MCMC already).  As it appears that MCMC is a common technique used in sequential MC, I will leave this answer up.

Comment: This answer does not seem to be related to particle filters / sequential Monte Carlo.